# How to use a variable in the mex compiling code sentence?

Tags: matlab, mex

I am compiling my c++ file into mex file. I will do some following manipulation to the mex file, like `copyfile` or `movefile`. So I want to use a variable of the c++ name. 
For example, I have a file `test.cpp`. 
Then I enter the following code in matlab command,

```
mex test.cpp
```

I want this:

```
filename = 'test';
mex [filename '.cpp'];
```

But it didn't work. Can I do it in any other way?

Comment: Its best if you compile your files and then used them. Why do you want to have such a thing at compilation stage? I think `mex([filename '.cpp'])` will work, but consider why do you even what to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MATLAB syntax

```
mex test.cpp
```

is the same as

```
mex('test.cpp')
```

This is true for **all** functions. The interpreter translates the first syntax into the second independent of which function is being called.

Thus, you can do:

```
filename = 'test.cpp';
mex(filename);
```

or

```
filename = 'test';
mex([filename,'.cpp']);
```

More generally:

```
mex -v -R2018a COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /fp:fast /arch:AVX2 /MT /Oi /GL" MyMatrixFunction.c;
```

Should become:

```
filename = 'MyMatrixFunction.c';
mex('-v', '-R2018a', 'COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /fp:fast /arch:AVX2 /MT /Oi /GL"', filename);
```

So each space is replaced with `,` and each word is closed with `' '`.